# Command prompt logging with xcopy

Tags: windows, command-line, dos, xcopy

I have an xcopy script that I'm running that reads in a .csv file with directories and file names and parses it to copy the files.

Here's the script:

```
echo F | for /f "delims=, tokens=1,2,3" %i in (D:\foo.csv) 
do xcopy /i /d "Z:\%i\%j\%k" "Y:\%i\%j\%k" >> "D:\xcopy\Log.txt"
```

The output to the command prompt are the commands being executed:

```
 echo F   | xcopy /i /d "Z:\hcri001\a1\
ffce5a14-33ca-43cf-b366-af266c450979" "Y:\hcri001\a1\ffce5a14-33ca-43cf-b366
-af266c450979"  1>>"D:\xopy\Log.txt
```

However, the log just has the output of the commands:

```
0 File(s) copied
0 File(s) copied
0 File(s) copied
Does Y:\hcri001\2d\545392db-50fa-40d9-aaa2-0892ca5057f3 specify a file name
or directory name on the target
(F = file, D = directory)? F
Z:\hcri001\2d\545392db-50fa-40d9-aaa2-0892ca5057f3
1 File(s) copied
```

Is there someway to have both the commands being executed, as well as the output?
Also, is there anyway to have some sort of counter that I can put in the beginning of the line?

My Ideal log file would be in this format:

```
    1) C:\Desktop>echo F   | xcopy /i /d "Z:\hcri001\a7\
    00a62a73-d7a7-4cfb-b55c-457bc67b3647" "Y:\hcri001\a7\00a62a73-d7a7-4cfb-b55c
    -457bc67b3647"  1>>"D:\Robocopy\AtlusPatient131172CopyLog.txt 
    0 File(s) copied
    2)    C:\Desktop>echo F   | xcopy /i /d "Z:\hcri001\d5\
    003452354-d7a7-4cfb-452c-457bc67b3647" "Y:\hcri001\d5\003452354-d7a7-4cfb-452c-457bc67b3647"  1>>"D:\Robocopy\AtlusPatient131172CopyLog.txt 
    0 File(s) copied
    3)   C:\Desktop>echo F   | xcopy /i /d "Z:\hcri001\2d\545392db-50fa-40d9-aaa2-0892ca5057f3" "Y:\hcri001\2d\545392db-50fa-40d9-aaa2-0892ca5057f3"  1>>"D:\Robocopy\AtlusPatient131172CopyLog.txt 
Does Y:\hcri001\2d\545392db-50fa-40d9-aaa2-0892ca5057f3 specify a file name
        or directory name on the target
        (F = file, D = directory)? F
        Z:\hcri001\2d\545392db-50fa-40d9-aaa2-0892ca5057f3
        1 File(s) copied
```

and bonus points if the command can be trimmed to just include the file name instead of the whole command i.e. `1) "Z:\hcri001\2d\545392db-50fa-40d9-aaa2-0892ca5057f3"
                     0 File(s) copied`

Comment: Did you try to redirect at the script level, instead of  inside the script? I mean a.cmd >> log.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=, tokens=1,2,3" %i in (D:\foo.csv) do (
  echo xcopy /i /d "Z:\%i\%j\%k" "Y:\%i\%j\%k" >> "D:\xcopy\Log.txt"
  echo f | xcopy /i /d "Z:\%i\%j\%k" "Y:\%i\%j\%k" >> "D:\xcopy\Log.txt"
)
```

For the counter you need `SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS` then `set counter=1`
and inside the loop `set /a counter=!counter! + 1`

Comment: The above is giving me the following error for each image it tries to copy: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.  Is it because it's trying to append the output to a log file while it's still writing the input to it?

Comment: I still can't seem to get this to run without the above error (even after modifying it a bit), is there something I'm missing?